# Home page of blog displays no posts

Tags: blog

I'm using the Illustratr theme. On the home page of my blog it says:

> NOTHING FOUND. It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.

This appears since I created it.
It only shows on that first page, which is static, and where I have only a gallery. 
Also when I post other content on that page, it stays there.
I don't know much about the coding, so changing the template is not really an option...

Thank you!

Comment: A quick Google search for `illustratr theme wordpress` seems to indicate that this is a wordpress.com theme. Are you trying to use it on a self-hosted WordPress installation, or are you have trouble using it on WordPress.com? If the latter, please consult [their support site](http://support.wordpress.com/) -- [WPSE's help pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically indicate wp.com support is outside this site's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Create a page for you Blog. Just the title only nothing else. I use 'Our Blog' for instance. Save it and make it public.

In your dashboard go to Settings|Reading

Use the drop down menu for "Post Page" to find the page you just created.

Scroll down and save the changes.

Your blog page should now show up in the site navigation menu and any blog posts should show up on that page.